# Git Add: pathspec didn't match any files

Tags: git, git-bash

I'm trying to add new files to my working directory and then register them by doing this:

```
git add filename.php
```

Yesterday I just double-checked on the remote gitlab location and all the new files from yesterday have been included.

However, now whenever I'm adding new files I get this error:

```
pathspec filename.php didn't match any files
```

If I do `git status`, it confirms that the new files are not being registered.

`ls` - new files are not showing up although they are physically located in the specific folder.

I haven't made any changes to `gitignore` or any other settings for that matter and I've double-checked that I'm in the right folder and on the right branch.

Comment: If files don't show up with `ls` then they don't exist. Are you adding from the directory where the files are? I.e., if you do `git add file` then you need to be in the directory where the file is. Otherwise you have to do `git add path/to/file`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do `git status`, does it show all the path to the file? like /path/to/filename.php. If this is the case, I always put all the path in `git add` like `git add /path/to/filename.php`

Comment: @Alex-Howansky & @Wuelber-Castillo, awesome, thank you. It was due to a misunderstood path. When I opened Git Bash today and it had `Username ~(branchname)` in the console, I assumed I am in my Working Directory.

Now thanks to your comments I tried
`git add /public_html/images/file.png`
and it responded:
`Fatal: could not switch to C:/Program Files/Git/blablabla`

For some reason it had switched to Program Files from C:/Users/username where my actual Working Directory is.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use space between the filename if similar name is used.
As for example if you already add a file named as test.txt then don't use test 2.txt.
Rather you can rename it as test_2.txt.